# ng build with `--prod` flag fails with `Error occurs in the template of component`

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-cli-v8

when i run the `ng build` it works fine. in case of `ng build --prod` throws following errors mostly. what is the issue how to fix them?

here is the errors:

```
app/pf-services/cms/components/translation-status/translation-status.component.ts:14:18
    14     templateUrl: './translation-status.component.html',
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component TranslationStatusComponent.
app/pf-services/cms/components/translation-status/translation-status.component.html:114:1 - error TS8001: 'shell-modals-popup' is not a valid HTML element.

114 <shell-modals-popup [popConfig]='popConfig' (reset)="reset()"></shell-modals-popup>
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  app/pf-services/cms/components/translation-status/translation-status.component.ts:14:18
    14     templateUrl: './translation-status.component.html',
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component TranslationStatusComponent.
app/pf-services/cms/components/translation-status/translation-status.component.html:114:21 - error TS8002: 'popConfig' is not a valid property of <shell-modals-popup>.

114 <shell-modals-popup [popConfig]='popConfig' (reset)="reset()"></shell-modals-popup>
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  app/pf-services/cms/components/translation-status/translation-status.component.ts:14:18
    14     templateUrl: './translation-status.component.html',
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component TranslationStatusComponent.
app/pf-services/cms/containers/shell-control-type/shell-control-type.component.html:1:1 - error TS8001: 'control-type' is not a valid HTML element.

  1 <control-type
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  2     [sourceData]="data | async"
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
...
  7     (miscActions)="miscActions($event)"
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  8 ></control-type>
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  app/pf-services/cms/containers/shell-control-type/shell-control-type.component.ts:11:16
    11   templateUrl: './shell-control-type.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component ShellControlTypeComponent.
app/pf-services/cms/containers/shell-control-type/shell-control-type.component.html:2:5 - error TS8002: 'sourceData' is not a valid property of <control-type>.
```

Comment: Try `ng serve --prod`, for me it produces better (i.e. more readable) error messages.

Comment: The `--prod` flag adds extra type checking. So you just need to fix the errors. If you don't know how we need a [mcve]

Comment: `ng serve --aot --prod` should display some detailed error msg

Comment: prod build use aot if you didnt change it in the angular.json, everything that you use in template must be public in ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure but you can try this:

**Before :**

```
<shell-modals-popup [popConfig]='popConfig' (reset)="reset()"></shell-modals-popup>
<control-type [sourceData]="data | async" (miscActions)="miscActions($event)"></control-type>
```

**After :**

```
<shell-modals-popup [popConfig]="popConfig" (reset)="reset()"></shell-modals-popup>
<control-type [sourceData]="{{data | async}}" (miscActions)="miscActions($event)"></control-type>
```

Comment: can you check point 11 in error list..? what is the problem there?

Comment: Maybe use dataSource instead of sourceData